# Spring RabbitMQ custom message converter in listener

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I am using RabbitMQ with Spring Integration. 
I want to register a message converter for a message listener like this:

```
<rabbit:listener-container
        connection-factory="gesbRabbitmqConnectionFactory"
        acknowledge="auto"
        channel-transacted="true"
        transaction-manager="rabbitTxManager"
        task-executor="gesbSyncExecutor"
        concurrency="1"
        max-concurrency="2"
        requeue-rejected="false"
        message-converter="gesbDataMessageConverter">
    <rabbit:listener
            ref="gesbListenerBean"
            queue-names="${gesb.partyid.queue}" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

When the application starts I've put a breakpoint in the setMessageConverter and my message converter gesbDataMessageConverter is set right.
But at runtime when the message arrives the message converter is the SimpleMessageConverter and not mine. 
Any ideas?

As a workaround I've injected the converter in the listener and called once again the setMessageConverter and it seems to work but I do not know why initially it didn't. There is only one listener object and the set method is called only once.

Comment: You can simply move your comment to the question via "edit" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is with the combination of Spring AMQP and Spring Integration.
The `AmqpInboundGateway` has its own `MessageConverter` property and uses it from the raw `MessageListener`.

I mean that you should supply your custom `gesbDataMessageConverter` exactly into the `<int-amqp:inbound-gateway>` instead of the container.

Comment: Hello Artem, I am not using a `int-ampq:inbound-gateway` but `int:gateway` but none of them supports the `message-converter` as I checked xsd. The only place to put it was on the container.

Comment: Hm. Don't you have some other container? Isn't there some AOP instrument which may override value in the field directly? Can you come up with some simple application which minimize boundaries of the problem? Since you can debug even Spring code that should not be a big deal for you